# Hide labels in overview map

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using QGIS 2.18.

In the overview map, is it possible to remove attribute labels?

I just want the labels in the primary map, but not the overlay.

All that yellow in the overlay image is the labels for the attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since your overview does not have the same scale as your main map, you should add a scale-based visibility rule to your label:

[image: Scale-based visibility for label]

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Please try the plugin "QuickMapServices" instead. What you describe is a known issue of openlayers plugin.